# Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the titles of the streams on https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Dota%202, using Requests and BeautifulSoup. I know that my search criteria are correct, yet my program does not find the elements I need.

Here is a screenshot showing the relevant part of the source code in the browser:

[image: Screenshot of the browser showing part of the webpage, as well as the source using the developer tools/web inspector.]

The HTML source as text:

```html
<div class="tw-media-card-meta__title">
  <div class="tw-c-text-alt">
    <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--button tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" data-a-target="preview-card-title-link" href="/weplayesport_en">
      <div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex">
        <h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="NAVI vs HellRaisers | BO5 | ODPixel &amp; S4 | WeSave! Charity Play">NAVI vs HellRaisers | BO5 | ODPixel &amp; S4 | WeSave! Charity Play</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Dota%202")

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")

title_elems = soup.find_all("h3", attrs={"title": True})

print(title_elems)
```

When I run it, `title_elems` is just the empty list (`[]`).

Why is my program not finding the elements?

Comment: also, can you share the output of that application if still in usage? 
If in-use and is semi-real time, my friend would love it.

Comment: @OakDev Which application are you referring to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The element you're interested in is dynamically generated, after the initial page load, which means that your browser executed JavaScript, made other network requests, etc. in order to build the page. Requests is just an HTTP library, and as such will not do those things.

You could use a tool like Selenium, or perhaps even analyze the network traffic for the data you need and make the requests directly.

Comment: if you've lucky, you might find out the XHR/Ajax requests that explicitly load content. See an example: https://webscraping.pro/scrape-lazy-load-page-python-requests/.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can do to grab the title of different games from that site using requests module:

```
import re
import requests

url = "https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Dota%202"
link = "https://gql.twitch.tv/gql"

formdata = [{"operationName":"DirectoryRoot_Directory","variables":{"name":"dota 2"},"extensions":{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"9f4f6ae67f21ee50b454fcf048691107a52bfe7907ead73b9427398e343ca319"}}},{"operationName":"Directory_DirectoryBanner","variables":{"name":"Dota 2"},"extensions":{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"a64b0348103e054cbdb20c58de5fc05160da3f86c37c80263d7e6282f2577f54"}}},{"operationName":"DirectoryPage_Game","variables":{"name":"dota 2","options":{"sort":"RELEVANCE","recommendationsContext":{"platform":"web"},"requestID":"JIRA-VXP-2397","tags":[]},"sortTypeIsRecency":False,"limit":30},"extensions":{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"f2ac02ded21558ad8b747a0b63c0bb02b0533b6df8080259be10d82af63d50b3"}}}]

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
    res = s.get(url)
    s.headers['Client-Id'] = re.findall(r"Client-ID\":\"(.*?)\"",res.text)[0]
    res = s.post(link,json=formdata)
    for item in res.json()[2]['data']['game']['streams']['edges']:
        print(item['node']['title'])
```

The type of results you may get:

```
PUBS 7.27 POG VIBE COOL FUN
Playing more 7.27
7.27 Pubs :) Climb to 9k
В новый сезон с новыми победами Custom Hero Chaos |  !discord 
Бобрый вечер !розыгрыш 
RERUN: Adroit vs Execration Game 1 - BTS Pro Series 2: SEA - Group Stage w/ MLP & johnxfire
(RU) Повтор | EGB.com Arena of Blood 
No Matter What
mid 5000-6000(5600) (!розыгрыш каждый день)
chegou a cam, pena que to parecendo um neanderthal
```