# Node missing data when scraping with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web scraper to pull financial data and analyst recommendations. I have an issue where the data seems to be missing / incorrect form the node when I Extract the data from the page source code I get $0.00 but The correct value is $884.23

Here is the example code below:

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

sym='cmg'
url='https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/{}/analyst-research'.format(sym)
page_response = rq.get(url, timeout=5)
page=bs(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
sr=page.find('div', attrs={'class':'analyst-target-price__price'})

print(sr.text)
Out[546]: '$0.00'
```

From the html code on the site the value should be $884.23 at the time of writing this question.

Like I was saying above I assume the issue is the site was not fully rendered when I got the page response / content. Does anyone have a solution to this ?

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML source, as it appears in your program?

Comment: Stop scraping sites, and just pay for the API.

Comment: Update: The issue is indeed that the content is dynamically generated, a common issue, and I have just the duplicate for the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 3):

the value you are trying to scrape is being genrated by Javascript so it's not in the source code of the page . 
You can get the same value by sending the same request js is making :

```
import requests as rq

sym            = 'cmg'
url            = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/analyst/{}/targetprice'.format(sym)
page_response  = rq.get(url).json()
priceTarget    = page_response['data']['consensusOverview']['priceTarget']
lowPriceTarget = page_response['data']['consensusOverview']['lowPriceTarget']
highPriceTarget = page_response['data']['consensusOverview']['highPriceTarget']

print('priceTarget',priceTarget)
print('lowPriceTarget ',lowPriceTarget )
print('highPriceTarget ',highPriceTarget )
```

OutPut:

```
priceTarget 884.23
lowPriceTarget  550.0
highPriceTarget  1050.0
```

Comment: _the value you are trying to scrape is being genrated by Javascript_ Can you share the relevant HTML, I can't find it in the page.

Comment: @AMC have a look at the answer . if you viewed the source code of the page you won't find the value there , that's what I mean by it's being generated by JS through an AJAX call .

Comment: _if you viewed the source code of the page you won't find the value there , that's what I mean by it's being generated by JS through an AJAX call ._ Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, I meant that I couldn't even find the div with class `'analyst-target-price__price'` in my browser. It turns out I needed to scroll down the page in order to get it to load.

Comment: @AMC Exactly anything that loads on scroll is being generated by JS .

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Thanks a lot ! worked out perfectly. How did you find the url for the request js is making (sorry kinda new to webscrapping and html)

Comment: @Charco accept the answer if it helped you , Through browser developer tools -> network tab and monitor the requests the website is making and for js requests -> XHR tab