# BeautifulSoup not returning children of element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and have been using BeautifulSoup to scrape numbers off a gambling website. I'm trying to get the text of a certain element but returned None.

Here is my code:

```
r=requests.get('https://roobet.com/crash')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

crash = soup.find('div', class_='CrashHistory_2YtPR')

print(crash)
```

When I copied the content of my soup into a note pad and tried ctrl+f to find the element i could not find it.
The element I'm looking for is in the `<div id="root">` element and when I looked closer at the copied soup in the notepad I saw that there was nothing inside the `<div id="root">` element.
I don't understand what is happening
how can I get the element I'm looking for.

Comment: Please share the relevant part(s) of the HTML source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Your website seems to be [dynamically loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page), meaning it uses Javascript and other components. You can test this by enabling/disabling Javascript. In order to scrape this site, try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/), you can also use other browsers, just look for their equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`Right click` on the page and `view source`. This is one sure way of knowing how the DOM looks like when the page loads. If you do this for the site `https://roobet.com/crash` you will notice that the `<body>` is almost empty besides some `<script>` elements.

This is because body of the webpage is dynamically loaded using Javascript. This is most likely done using a framework such as `react`

This is the reason `BeautifulSoup` is having trouble finding the element.