# BeautifulSoup.find_all() method not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new in BeautifulSoup

Today, As an example I just try to get all the link from random website. However, find_all func. return only empty list.

I checked all topic in there and google but, I couldn't find any solution.

Here is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://yellowpages.com.tr/ara?q=ankara"
response = requests.get(url)  # Get Url into Code

html_content = response.content  # Make Usable

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")  # Make Particle

for i in soup.find_all("link"):
    print(i)
print("Finished")
```

Comment: Have you tried to print html_content and see if link exists? Your page has some dynamic loading and the initial request does not return the page with links on it.

Comment: print(html_content) gives:b'<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang="en-US">\n\n<head>\n    <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n

Comment: Looking at how the page loads I think you will have to use Selenuim.

Comment: print(response) gives [503] output. I'm new at BeautifulSoup. Maybe [503] has some meaning. In my example, course video get [200]

Comment: @Jortega just asking to learn. How do you decide that ?

Comment: It looks like the creators of the website are using javascript to dynamically add things to the page.  I went to the url you posted and it only showed a loading bar. After it loaded the page changed and the url also changed without me doing anything. Try using the url for this page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567278/beautifulsoup-find-all-method-not-working?noredirect=1#comment108906033_61567278

Comment: Did you check that the elements are present in the HTML source you receive?

Answer (score 0):

See this [Answer here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60904787/4539709)
*You will need to use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) to get the page and wait for it to load.*

*basic example would be*

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://yellowpages.com.tr/ara?q=ankara")
time.sleep(10)  # wait for page to load

# then use beautifulsoup to get what you need
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all("link"):
    print(i)
```

---

> *For Firefox [webdriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) download geckodriver.exe*
>
> *For Chrome [Webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) download chromedriver.exe*

Comment: well this is not what he was looking for, the OP is how to do it using beautifulsoup

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi 0m3r is likely suggesting this because the content that OP is after is generated through JS.

Comment: @AMC then he should explain the reason for his recommendation.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi _then he should explain the reason for his recommendation._ That's true, yes. In any case, many people have already pointed it out, and I submitted a dupe target.