# Python 3 urllib library not returning the same HTML as inspected on Chrome

Tags: python

So I'm trying to extract the current EUR/USD price from a website using Python urllib but the website does not send the same HTML it sends to Chrome. The first part of the HTML is the same as on Chrome but it does not want to give me the EUR/USD value. Can I somehow bypass this?
Here's the code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

while True:
    req = Request('https://www.strategystocks.co.uk/currencies-market.html', headers={"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})

    html = urlopen(req).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    print(soup)

    buy = int(soup.find("span", class_="buyPrice").text)

    sell = int(soup.find("span", class_="sellPrice").text)

    print("Buy", buy)
    print("Sell", sell)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded via Javascript, but you can simulate the Ajax request with `requests` library:

```
import requests

url = 'https://marketools.plus500.com/Feeds/UpdateTable?instsIds=2&isUseSentiments=true'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# print(data) # <-- uncomment this to print all data

print('Buy  =',data['Feeds'][0]['B'])
print('Sell =',data['Feeds'][0]['S'])
```

Prints:

```
Buy  = 1.08411
Sell = 1.08403
```