# How can I scrape the Rank, name of fund and yearly returns?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the website: https://www.crisil.com/en/home/what-we-do/financial-products/mf-ranking.html

This is what I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
test = soup.find_all('div', class_ = ['col-xs-12 col-md-10','best-perfom-wrapper table-owl'])
for tests in test:
        print(tests.getText())
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Are you familiar with using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I was not getting the table like even after adding the class name under div tags, all i got was an empty list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, but you can use `requests` module to load it.

For example:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.crisil.com/content/crisil/en/home/what-we-do/financial-products/mf-ranking/_jcr_content/wrapper_100_par/tabs/1/mf_rating.mfRating.json?categoryName=ELSS&displayName=&fundName=&invType=Equity&start=&limit=50&planName=Regular'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print( json.dumps(data, indent=4) )

print('{:<5}{:<65}{:<18}{:<18}'.format('Rank', 'Name', '1-Year Return', '3-Year Return'))
for d in data['docs']:
    print('{:<5}{:<65}{:<18}{:<18}'.format(d['crisilCprRanking'], d['schemeName'], d['scheme1YearReturn'], d['scheme3YearReturn']))
```

Prints:

```
Rank Name                                                             1-Year Return     3-Year Return     
1    Axis Long Term Equity Fund - Growth                              -8.2257           5.3486            
1    Canara Robeco Equity Tax Saver - Regular Plan - Growth           -9.5095           3.9286            
1    BOI AXA Tax Advantage Fund - Regular Plan - Growth               -3.2405           3.669             
2    BNP Paribas Long Term Equity Fund - Growth                       -8.1381           1.7356            
2    Aditya Birla Sun Life Tax Relief 96 - Regular Plan - Growth      -10.7236          1.5953            
2    LIC MF Tax Plan 1997 - Growth                                    -15.1941          0.0864            
2    JM Tax Gain Fund - Growth                                        -14.8988          -0.0959           
2    Kotak Tax Saver Scheme - Growth                                  -14.4158          -0.1061           
2    IDBI Equity Advantage Fund - Growth                              -10.0082          -0.3625           
3    Mirae Asset Tax Saver Fund - Regular Plan - Growth               -12.5824          3.1051            
3    Invesco India Tax Plan - Growth                                  -10.647           2.542             
3    Taurus Taxshield - Growth                                        -14.1226          0.8283            
3    Union Long Term Equity Fund - Growth                             -10.621           0.2545            
3    Tata India Tax Savings Fund - Regular Plan - Growth              -16.1544          0.1772            
3    DSP Tax Saver Fund - Regular Plan - Growth                       -13.4712          0.1257            
3    ICICI Prudential Long Term Equity Fund (Tax Saving) - Growth     -16.4059          -0.0622           
3    UTI Long Term Equity Fund (Tax Saving) - Growth                  -11.591           -0.0687           
3    PGIM India Long Term Equity Fund - Growth                        -15.4341          -1.2691           
3    Motilal Oswal Long Term Equity Fund - Growth                     -14.5569          -2.3176           
3    Essel Long Term Advantage Fund - Growth                          -17.3935          -2.4477           
3    Edelweiss Long Term Equity Fund (Tax Savings) - Growth           -16.8778          -2.5307           
3    HSBC Tax Saver Equity Fund - Growth                              -17.7209          -4.1052           
3    Baroda ELSS - 96 - Plan A - Growth                               -16.4446          -4.8066           
4    Mahindra Manulife ELSS Kar Bachat Yojana - Regular Plan - Growth -16.6422          -0.1001           
4    Principal Tax Saving Fund                                        -16.9895          -2.1699           
4    SBI Long Term Equity Fund - Growth                               -16.2047          -2.8161           
4    L&T Tax Advantage Fund - Growth                                  -16.5168          -2.8685           
4    IDFC Tax Advantage (ELSS) Fund - Regular Plan - Growth           -23.3668          -3.8445           
4    Franklin India Taxshield Fund - Growth                           -22.1332          -3.9637           
5    HDFC Tax Saver Fund - Growth                                     -23.2624          -5.7864           
5    Sundaram Diversified Equity - Growth                             -22.8637          -5.8186           
5    Nippon India Tax Saver Fund - Growth                             -29.85            -11.2411
```

Comment: Woah Woah Woah! How did you get to know the "url" that you just used? It would be helpful in getting me other data too! Also THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @KaiwalyaPatil I observed in Firefox Developer Tools where the page is making requests. (Chrome has something similar too)

Comment: What I didn't understand is, this part of website: /_jcr_content/wrapper_100_par/tabs/1/mf_rating.mfRating.json?

Comment: @KaiwalyaPatil That's part of Ajax URL - the page is making request from JavaScript to this URL to obtain the information.

Comment: I got it in Chrome. Thanks a lot! This is something that just blows my head off!