# Hidden element can not found by Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

can some help me when I print out (samples) it shows an empty list or None
I think there are some missing tags.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
class scrape:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content=None
        self.soup=None 
        self.samples=None 
        self.lastSamples=None 
        self.numbers=None
    def Download(self):
        results=requests.get("https://www.bet.co.za/bet-games/")
        print(results)
        if results.status_code==200:
           self.content=results.content
        else:
            
           raise Exception("Download: Could not fetch data")
    def findSoupSamples(self):
        self.soup=BeautifulSoup(self.content,"html.parser")
        self.samples=self.soup.find('div',{'class':'game-result'})
        print(self.samples)
```

Comment: There's no `game-result` class in the HTML of that site. They're probably added dynamically by JavaScript.

Comment: this page uses JavaScript but `BS` can't run JavaScript so you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Comment: how can i do it by using selenuim ?

Comment: in my previous comment you can see link to [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  and there you can find [Simple Usage](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage). You can also use `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)` after `driver.get(url)` in example. But you may need `time.sleep(seconds)` or [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait until JavaScript add elements to page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal example which uses [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which loads page and run JavaScript.

Because JavaScript needs some time to add elements so I use `time.sleep(10)` but you can use special function to wait for elements. See [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Because `div.game-result` is inside `<iframe>` so first I have to find `iframe` and switch to this iframe. In example I check in all iframes but you chould use only `all_iframes[1]` to get elements.

`Selenium` has many functions `find_element_by_...` and `find_elements_by_... to search elements in HTML so you could do it without` BeautifulSoup`

```
import selenium.webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bet.co.za/bet-games/")

time.sleep(10)

all_iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print('len(all_iframes):', len(all_iframes))

for number, iframe in enumerate(all_iframes):
    print('--- iframe', number, '---')
    
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    samples = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'game-result'})
    print('len(samples):', len(samples))

    for item in samples:
        print(item.get_text(separator=','))
    
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Result:

```
len(all_iframes): 4
--- iframe 0 ---
len(samples): 0
--- iframe 1 ---
len(samples): 5
13,15,35,21,4
3,14,4,25,33
25,34,14,4,8
30,18,25,24,10
35,30,5,34,21
--- iframe 2 ---
len(samples): 0
--- iframe 3 ---
len(samples): 0
```

---

**EDIT:** Similar version with one `iframe` and without `BeautifulSoup`

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bet.co.za/bet-games/")

time.sleep(10)

all_iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(all_iframes[1])

all_samples = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.game-result')
print('len(all_samples):', len(all_samples))

for sample in all_samples:
    all_balls = sample.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.ball-item')
    all_text = [ball.text for ball in all_balls]
    print(','.join(all_text))
```

Result:

```
len(all_samples): 5
13,1,12,2,10
13,14,33,26,4
21,18,12,9,4
13,15,35,21,4
3,14,4,25,33
```

---

**BTW:** Sometimes page displays video instead of these numbers and then code may gives empty strings. It may need more complex code to wait for end of video.

---

**EDIT:**

To change game you have to find link to  `Lucky 7` and `click()` it

```
all_titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.game-title')
all_titles[6].click()
```

Minimal working example

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bet.co.za/bet-games/")

time.sleep(10)

all_iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(all_iframes[1])

all_titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.game-title')
print('len(all_titles):', len(all_titles))
# click on link to `Lucky 7`
all_titles[6].click()
time.sleep(1)

all_samples = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.game-result')
print('len(all_samples):', len(all_samples))

for sample in all_samples:
    all_balls = sample.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.ball-item')
    all_text = [ball.text for ball in all_balls]
    print(','.join(all_text))
```

**BTW:**

Normally you could also use text

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Lucky 7')
link.click()
```

but this element is not in `<a>` so it doesn't work.

But works:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Lucky 7"]')
link.click()
```

Comment: thank you sir but I want to extract luck7, not lucky5

Comment: you didn't say it in question. You have to find link to `lucky7` and `.click()`  it. `Selenium` has many different functions `find_elements_by_...` to search elements.