# Trouble collecting some values from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch some dynamic values out of a table from a webpage. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Bym.jpg) represents the values I wish to grab from that page. There should be any way to grab them using requests. To let you know, I looked for any hidden api in dev tools and also went through the script tags in page source to find out the values but I could not.

This is the [site url](https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment)

This is the [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Bym.jpg) I'm after.

This is I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment"

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".dfx-technicalSentimentCard__barContainer"):
    data = [item.get("data-value") for item in items.select("[data-type='long-value-info'],[data-type='short-value-info']")]
    print(data)
```

The above script produces empty output like below:

```
['--', '--']
['--', '--']
['--', '--']
['--', '--']
['--', '--']
['--', '--']
['--', '--']
```

> How can I get the values from that table using requests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Comment: I've already mentioned in my above post what you have written in your answer there @AMC. An useless link anyway.

Comment: I don’t understand, what do you mean? I can’t see really see anything in your post that relates to the question I linked to.

Comment: What does this line mean `analyze the network traffic for the data you need and make the requests directly`? This is what really my question here. Thanks.

Comment: I’m confused. This entire post is about that?

Comment: It will use `Ajax` to load the page.If you don't want to use `selenium`,you need to find the `Ajax` API and get the data you need.

Answer (score 8):

Since the content load dynamically you have to use selenium to collect required information

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

driver.get('https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment')

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
for items in soup.select(".dfx-technicalSentimentCard__barContainer"):
    data = [item.get("data-value") for item in items.select("[data-type='long-value-info'],[data-type='short-value-info']")]
    print(data)

driver.quit()
```

For this code we can see the following output:

```
['43', '57']
['53', '47']
['38', '62']
['56', '44']
['57', '43']
['39', '61']
['48', '52']
['77', '23']
['41', '59']
['55', '45']
['56', '44']
['74', '26']
['65', '35']
['87', '13']
['55', '45']
['32', '68']
['43', '57']
['45', '55']
['64', '36']
['56', '44']
['84', '16']
['86', '14']
['97', '3']
['90', '10']
```

Comment: you deserve that bounty

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem. The problem is the figures are dynamic. If you check the page source, you cannot find those numbers but "--" only.

`item_list = soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"dfx-technicalSentimentCard__barContainer"}) print(item_list[-1])`

```html
<div class="dfx-technicalSentimentCard__barContainer">
<div class="dfx-sentimentPercentageBar dfx-sentimentPercentageBar--textHidden dfx-technicalSentimentCard__bar">
<div class="dfx-sentimentPercentageBar__long font-weight-bold" data-market-id="LTCUSD" data-stream-type="sentiment" data-type="long-bar" data-value="--">
</div>
<div class="dfx-sentimentPercentageBar__short font-weight-bold" data-market-id="LTCUSD" data-stream-type="sentiment" data-type="short-bar" data-value="--">
</div>
</div>
<div class="dfx-technicalSentimentCard__netLongContainer">
<span class="dfx-technicalSentimentCard__netLongText">Net Long</span>
<span class="dfx-rateDetail__percentageInfoText font-weight-bold" data-market-id="LTCUSD" data-stream-type="sentiment" data-type="long-value-info" data-value="--"></span>
</div>
<div class="dfx-technicalSentimentCard__netShortContainer">
<span class="dfx-technicalSentimentCard__netShortText">Net Short</span>
<span class="dfx-rateDetail__percentageInfoText font-weight-bold" data-market-id="LTCUSD" data-stream-type="sentiment" data-type="short-value-info" data-value="--"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

So you should switch to Selenium to get those figures