# Why is my code looping through only the first webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am just messing around with BeautifulSoup and testing it on different websites after recently learning about it. I am currently trying to iterate through multiple pages instead of just the first page. I can append or write the information I am grabbing from any specific page that I desire but of course I would love to automate it.

This is my current code when trying to get it to work up to page five. Currently it only goes through the first webpage and writes the same info I am looking for to my excel file, five times. In my nested for loop I have some print statements just to see if it is working on the console before I even look in the file.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import unicodecsv as csv

f = open("on_sale_games.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8')
headers = "Game name, Original price, Final price, Percent off\n"
f.write(headers)

for i in range(5):
    my_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/specials#p={}&tab=TopSellers'.format(i+1)

    uClient = uReq(my_url)  # open up the url and download the page.
    page_html = uClient.read()  # reading the html page and storing the info into page_html.
    uClient.close()  # closing the page.

    page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')  # html parsing

    containers = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class": "tab_item"})

    for container in containers:
        name_stuff = container.findAll("div", {"class": "tab_item_name"})
        name = name_stuff[0].text
        print("Game name:", name)

        original_price = container.findAll("div", {"class": "discount_original_price"})
        original = original_price[0].text
        print("Original price:", original)

        discounted_price = container.findAll("div", {"class": "discount_final_price"})
        final = discounted_price[0].text
        print("Discounted price:", final)

        discount_pct = container.findAll("div", {"class": "discount_pct"})
        pct = discount_pct[0].text
        print("Percent off:", pct)

        f.write(name.replace(':', '').replace("™", " ") + ',' + original + ',' + final + ',' + pct + '\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: Typo in the URL: `#p` should be `?p`

Comment: @Barmar They both seem to return a similar webpage.

Comment: See the answer below. The web page uses JavaScript to dynamically update the page, but BS doesn't run JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking through the requests made by the browser, I noticed there's a request made in the background to fetch the data and get `json` result, you could work your way from there:

```
for i in range(5):
    my_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/contenthub/querypaginated/specials/NewReleases/render/?query=&start={}'.format(i*15)
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    data = json.loads(page_html)["results_html"]
    page_soup = soup(data, 'html.parser')
    # Rest of the code
```

It's like an API that get's 15 elements per page, so it's starts at 0, 15, 30 and so on.

Comment: What are you talking about? AJAX is in browsers, this is server code.

Comment: Python doesn't perform `urlopen()` in the background.

Comment: But I agree that it's better to use the API rather than scrape HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I might have expressed myself in a wrong way.

Comment: Are you saying that the web page he's scraping is using AJAX to fill in the DOM dynamically?

Comment: Yes, when you click on pages, you'll see the requests are made to fetch the data, so yes it's dynamically.

Comment: @b14d35 I am not getting the results I was looking for with this solution but I do think I am on the right track with the information you both have given me.

Comment: @Mooker Please check again the code, I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @b14d35 thanks! I was just in the middle of implementing a solution with your original answer and although mine was a little different, seemed to do the trick. Appreciate the help.